# jQuery each for collection of strings

Tags: jquery, arrays, foreach

The code below throws an exception in firefox:

```
 $(function(){
        $(["one","two","three"]).each(function(){
            if(this == "one")
                $("div#msg").html(this);
        });
    });
```

the exception is this:

**Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]**

Yet if I change code and use this.toString() as follows, it works:

```
$(function(){
    $(["one","two","three"]).each(function(){
        if(this == "one")
            $("div#msg").html(this.toString());
    });
});
```

If "this" is a string, why do I need to do toString()? Is there a nuance of javaScript which I am missing or am I just being a moron? Please tell me it's a nuance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Distinction between string primitives and String objects** JavaScript automatically converts primitives and String objects, so that it's possible to use String object methods for primitive strings. In contexts where a method is to be invoked on a primitive string or a property lookup occurs, JavaScript will automatically wrap the string primitive and call the method or perform the property lookup.

~From MDN [**Read More**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects)

```
$("div#msg").html("one"); //works

$("div#msg").html(new String("one")); // doesnt work
```

For ex:

```
try {         
    $("div#msg").html(new String("one"));
} catch (e) {
    $("div#msg").html("Can't use String object");
}
```

And the output of the div is `Can't use String object`. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/pEwYu/1/) here

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it do not work with array. Try this.

```
 $(["one","two","three"]).each(function(i, val){
        if(val == "one")
            $("div#msg").html(val);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

if you try this:

```
 $(function(){
        $(["one","two","three"]).each(function(){
            console.log(this);
            console.log(this.toString());
        });
    });
```

you'll see in the console that `this` and `this.toString()` aren't actually the same thing. It would seem that `this` is a String object and that `this.toString()` is an actual string.